# Can we enable Accessibility feature for only one textview?

Tags: android, accessibility

I working in an application where I need read the text from Textview using Accessibility feature.

I have already tired with TextToSpeech and it's working fine, but any how I am trying with Talkback also

Could some here, please let me know whether I can enable accessibility features only for my application and single Textview only?

I have tired with the below code and it's not working

```
txtView.requestFocus();
txtView.announceForAccessibility(text);
```

Can we speak certain text. For instance " He is very good"

Answer (score 1):

Nope, you can't do that. You can see talkback/accessibility as a device mode. It is not specific to any particular view.

your device will treat the whole screen (including each and every app) as it is used by vision affected person.

Once you enter into accessibility mode, your code will work. because it points to **Accessibility Mode**